# Merge Surefire Reports

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

In my projects I have several modules. when I  generate reports using the surefire maven plugin, it created reports for each module separately. I want to merge this reports. Is there any way to merge this separate reports. Any configurations in surefire plugin ?

thanks,

Comment: Exactly the problem at hand! How did you finally achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look to the tag

`<reportsDirectory>`

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<aggregate>true</aggregate>
```

For example:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```